# Creating self-referential tables with polymorphism in SQLALchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a db structure in which I have many types of content entities, of which one, a Comment, can be attached to any other.

Consider the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Unicode, Integer, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.orm import relation, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Entity(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entities'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    edited_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow, nullable=False)
    type = Column(Unicode(20), nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}

# <...insert some models based on Entity...>

class Comment(Entity):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': u'comment'}
    id = Column(None, ForeignKey('entities.id'), primary_key=True)
    _idref = relation(Entity, foreign_keys=id, primaryjoin=id == Entity.id)
    attached_to_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entities.id'), nullable=False)
    #attached_to = relation(Entity, remote_side=[Entity.id])
    attached_to = relation(Entity, foreign_keys=attached_to_id,
                           primaryjoin=attached_to_id == Entity.id,
                           backref=backref('comments', cascade="all, delete-orphan"))

    text = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=False)

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This seems about right, except SQLAlchemy doesn't like having two foreign keys pointing to the same parent. It says `ArgumentError: Can't determine join between 'entities' and 'comments'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.`

How do I specify `onclause`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to supplement your `Comment.__mapper_args__` to:

```
__mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_identity': 'comment',
    'inherit_condition': (id == Entity.id),
}
```

P.S. I haven't understand what you need `_idref` relationship for? If you want to use a comment somewhere where `Entity` is expected you could just pass the `Comment` instance as is.

Comment: The _idref was an attempt to clarify to SQLAlchemy which relation refers to what. It's of no use in my code.

Comment: So I just tried this and it's fixed the problem, but introduced a new one: deleting any other entity (which has a backref from this model, but no instance) fails with `TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`

Comment: Haven't understand your comment completely but look like you're messed up with built-in Python `id()` function. Did you forget to prepend id with `self.`? Or did you move `__mapper_args__` in class declaration *after* declaration of `id` field?

Comment: Ah! That was it. `__mapper_args__` was *before* id. Should have been after. It's working now.

Comment: This answer helped me as well...I know this is a little late OP but is there a reason why this works? Maybe a link to the docs would be enlightening. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To supplement @nailxx's answer:
Repeating all that boilerplate is tedious if you have many dependent tables.
Solution: move it all to a metaclass.

```
class EntityMeta(type(Entity)):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        ident = dct.get('_identity',None)
        if '__abstract__' not in dct:
            xid = Column(None, ForeignKey(Entity.id), primary_key=True)
            setattr(cls,'id',xid)
            setattr(cls,'__mapper_args__', { 'polymorphic_identity': dct['_identity'], 'inherit_condition': (xid == Entity.id,), 'primary_key':(xid,) })
            setattr(cls,'__tablename__',name.lower())
        super(EntityMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)

class EntityRef(Entity):
    __abstract__ = True
    __metaclass__ = EntityMeta

class Comment(EntityRef):
    _identity = 'comment'
    [...]
```

Variations, as an exercise for the reader: You can omit the `_identity=…` statement and use the class name, as in the `setattr(cls,'__tablename__',…)` line. Or not overwrite an existing __tablename__ or __mapper_args__ attribute.

Be sure to test `dct` and not `cls` for existence: the latter will find attributes in the parent class, which you obviously do not want at this point.