# SQLAlchemy InvalidRequestError when inserting to automap generated ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use the SQLAlchemy automap extension to generate an ORM for an existing database, and am getting an InvalidRequestError exception ("Instance  cannot be refreshed - it's not  persistent and does not contain a full primary key.") whenever I try to insert into a table that uses a composite primary key consisting of a timestamp and a foreign key.

Here's some minimal example code that reproduces the problem:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

db_schema_cmds = [
    '''CREATE TABLE users
    (
        u_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT Key1 PRIMARY KEY (u_id)
    );''',
    '''CREATE TABLE posts
    (
        timestamp TEXT NOT NULL,
        text TEXT NOT NULL,
        u_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT Key2 PRIMARY KEY (timestamp,u_id),
        CONSTRAINT users_have_posts FOREIGN KEY (u_id) REFERENCES users (u_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    );''']

# Create a new in-memory SQLite DB and execute the schema SQL commands.
db_engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
with db_engine.connect() as db_conn:
    for cmd in db_schema_cmds:
        db_conn.execute(text(cmd))

# Use automap to reflect the DB schema and generate ORM classes.
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(db_engine, reflect=True)

# Create aliases for the table classes generated.
User = Base.classes.users
Post = Base.classes.posts

session_factory = sessionmaker()
session_factory.configure(bind=db_engine)

# Add a user and a post to the DB.
session = session_factory()
new_user = User(name="John")
session.add(new_user)
session.commit()
new_post = Post(users=new_user, text='this is a test', timestamp=func.now())
session.add(new_post)
session.commit()

# Verify that the insertion worked.
new_user_id = session.execute(select([User])).fetchone()['u_id']
new_post_fk_user_id = session.execute(select([Post])).fetchone()['u_id']
assert new_user_id == new_post_fk_user_id

session.close()
```

Running this gives the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reproduce_InvalidRequestError.py", line 67, in <module>
    session.commit()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 801, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 392, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 372, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2019, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2137, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 186, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2107, in _flush
    flush_context.finalize_flush_changes()
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 395, in finalize_flush_changes
    self.session._register_newly_persistent(other)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1510, in _register_newly_persistent
    instance_key = mapper._identity_key_from_state(state)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 2417, in _identity_key_from_state
    for col in self.primary_key
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 2417, in <listcomp>
    for col in self.primary_key
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 578, in get
    value = state._load_expired(state, passive)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state.py", line 474, in _load_expired
    self.manager.deferred_scalar_loader(self, toload)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 647, in load_scalar_attributes
    "contain a full primary key." % state_str(state))
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Instance <posts at 0x45d45f8> cannot be refreshed - it's not  persistent and does not contain a full primary key.
```

If I add an `echo=True` parameter to the `create_engine` call, I see it is generating the following SQL for the insertion. This SQL works fine when I run it in DB Browser for SQLite.

```
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT users.u_id AS users_u_id, users.name AS users_name FROM users WHERE users.u_id = ?
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1,)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO posts (timestamp, text, u_id) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, ?)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('this is a test', 1)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

I also tried removing the `users` parameter from `Post()` and instead adding the line `new_user.posts_collection.append(new_post)` before calling `session.add(new_post)`, but that resulted in the same SQL being generated and the same error occurring.

If I replace the composite key with a new integer PK column, everything works fine. (Not an ideal solution though, as the reason I'm using `automap` is to reflect an *existing* DB, so it's preferable not to have to modify that DB's schema.)

I found a similar question, [SQLAlchemy InvalidRequestError when using composite foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238260/sqlalchemy-invalidrequesterror-when-using-composite-foreign-keys), however that seemed to be related to the use of inheritance in the table ORM classes, and the solution depended on defining the ORM table classes, rather than reflecting a DB to generate them.

Edit: I had originally assumed that this problem was related to the fact that my composite primary key contained a foreign key. The accepted answer shows that the foreign key was not actually a contributing factor to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for providing a perfect [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not actually the composite primary key with the foreign key, but the `func.now()` passed as `timestamp`, which is part of the primary key. As the value is not known to SQLAlchemy, since it is generated during insert in the database, it cannot perform the post-fetch; it has no idea what to fetch. If the DB in question supported `RETURNING` or similar, you'd be able to do this. See the note on [triggered columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#triggered-columns), which describes this exact situation. Pre-executing SQL for primary key values is also covered in [Defaults / SQL Expressions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#sql-expressions).

The reason why it works with an integer surrogate primary key is that SQLite does have a mechanism for [fetching the last inserted row id](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) (an integer primary key column), which SQLAlchemy is able to use.

To remedy this you can use a timestamp generated in Python

```
In [8]: new_post = Post(users=new_user, text='this is a test',
   ...:                 timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
   ...: session.add(new_post)
   ...: session.commit()
   ...:
```

The other solution would be to override the `timestamp` column during reflection and to provide `func.now()` as the default. This would trigger the pre-execution of `func.now()`.

```
   ...: # Use automap to reflect the DB schema and generate ORM classes.
   ...: Base = automap_base()
   ...: 
   ...: # Override timestamp column before reflection
   ...: class Post(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'posts'
   ...:     timestamp = Column(Text, nullable=False, primary_key=True,
   ...:                        default=func.now())
   ...: 
   ...: Base.prepare(db_engine, reflect=True)
   ...: 
   ...: # Create aliases for the table classes generated.
   ...: User = Base.classes.users
   ...: # Post has already been declared
   ...: #Post = Base.classes.posts
```

With the default in place, you do not need to (and shouldn't) provide `timestamp` when creating new instances

```
In [6]: new_post = Post(users=new_user, text='this is a test')
   ...: session.add(new_post)
   ...: session.commit()
   ...:
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation, thanks! I'll edit my post to remove the speculation about foreign keys being the cause.