# Change SQLAlchemy Primary Key after it has been defined

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

**Problem**: Simply put, I am trying to redefine a SQLAlchemy ORM table's primary key after it has already been defined.

**Example**:

```
class Base:

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return f"{cls.__name__}"


    @declared_attr
    def id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, cls.seq, unique=True, 
                      autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)

Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)

class A_Table(Base):
    newPrimaryKeyColumnsDerivedFromAnotherFunction = []
    # Please Note: as the variable name tries to say,
    # these columns are auto-generated and not known until after all
    # ORM classes (models) are defined

# OTHER CLASSES


def changePriKeyFunc(model):
    pass # DO STUFF

# Then do
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=arbitraryEngine)
# After everything has been altered and tied into a little bow
```

*Please note, this is a simplification of the true problem I am trying to solve.

**Possible Solution**: Your first thought might have been to do something like this:

```
def possibleSolution(model):
    for pricol in model.__table__.primary_key:
        pricol.primary_key = False

    model.__table__.primary_key = PrimaryKeyConstraint(
        *model.newPrimaryKeyColumnsDerivedFromAnotherFunction,

        # TODO: ADD all the columns that are in the model that are also a primary key
        # *[col for col in model.__table__.c if col.primary_key]
        )
```

But, this doesn't work, because when trying to add, flush, and commit, an error gets thrown:

```
InvalidRequestError: Instance <B_Table at 0x104aa1d68> cannot be refreshed - 
it's not persistent and does not contain a full primary key.
```

Even though this:

```
In [2]: B_Table.__table__.primary_key
Out[2]: PrimaryKeyConstraint(Column('a_TableId', Integer(),
                                    ForeignKey('A_Table.id'), table=<B_Table>, 
                                    primary_key=True, nullable=False))
```

as well as this:

```
In [3]: B_Table.__table__
Out[3]: Table('B_Table', MetaData(bind=None), 
              Column('id', Integer(), table=<B_Table>, nullable=False,
                     default=Sequence('test_1', start=1, increment=1, 
                                      metadata=MetaData(bind=None))), 
              Column('a_TableId', Integer(), 
                     ForeignKey('A_Table.id'), table=<B_Table>, 
                     primary_key=True, nullable=False), 
              schema=None)
```

and finally:

```
In [5]: b.a_TableId
Out[5]: 1
```

Also note that the database actually reflects the changed (and true) primary key, so I know that there's something going on with the ORM/SQLAlchemy.

**Question**: In summary, how can I change the model's primary key after the model has already been defined?

edit: See below for full code (same type of error, just in SQLite)

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.schema import PrimaryKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy import Sequence, create_engine


class Base:

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return f"{cls.__name__}"

    @declared_attr
    def seq(cls):
        return Sequence("test_1", start=1, increment=1)

    @declared_attr
    def id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, cls.seq, unique=True, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)


Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)


def relate(model, x):
    """Model is the original class, x is what class needs to be as
    an attribute for model"""

    attributeName = x.__tablename__
    idAttributeName = "{}Id".format(attributeName)
    setattr(model, idAttributeName,
            Column(ForeignKey(x.id)))
    setattr(model, attributeName,
            relationship(x,
                         foreign_keys=getattr(model, idAttributeName),
                         primaryjoin=getattr(
                             model, idAttributeName) == x.id,
                         remote_side=x.id
                         )
            )
    return model.__table__.c[idAttributeName]


def possibleSolution(model):
    if len(model.defined):
        newPriCols = []
        for x in model.defined:
            newPriCols.append(relate(model, x))

        for priCol in model.__table__.primary_key:
            priCol.primary_key = False
            priCol.nullable = True

        model.__table__.primary_key = PrimaryKeyConstraint(
            *newPriCols
            # TODO: ADD all the columns that are in the model that are also a primary key
            # *[col for col in model.__table__.c if col.primary_key]
            )


class A_Table(Base):
    pass


class B_Table(Base):
    defined = [A_Table]


possibleSolution(B_Table)

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

a = A_Table()
b = B_Table(A_TableId=a.id)

print(B_Table.__table__.primary_key)

session.add(a)
session.commit()
session.add(b)
session.commit()
```

Comment: My first thought was just keep the auto-increment primary key, and have another column with an index for your 'other' key value. Is that possible?

Comment: @SuperShoot You can assume that the id column does not get removed. As for having another column, I’m not sure what you mean.

Comment: I just mean add another column in your table, call it `other_id`, put an index on it so that it is fast to query on, and set the value of that column to the value that can only be generated once the object has already been created to save you from messing with the PK once it exists. If you can't alter the schema then this isn't an option, but that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Sorry I just realise that you don't want to change the primary key value of rows stored in a table, you want to change the definition of a table's primary key before you actually create the tables in the database based on some variable tied in to the creation of the ORM Class itself, right? My bad.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39384996/6560549) question? They were getting the same error as you and it was to do with having a database function (`func.now()`) in the PK which is only evaluated by the database once the sql is executed. Therefore SQLAlchemy has no way of knowing what the primary key is to fetch the data back from the database after the insert. Anything like that in your `changePriKeyFunc`?

Comment: @SuperShoot Yes, I did. It’s nothing to do with the database function, as without the change of primary key (aka changePriKeyFunc), the error is not thrown but the problem is not solved. In other words, when id is left as the primary key, and I create an object without passing in an argument for “id”, it does just fine adding it to the session, and even refreshes with the next integer in the sequence from the database.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of a Primary Key that has been generated by your function and how you are instantiating an instance of that object which raises the `InvalidRequestError` upon 'add/flush/commit'?

Comment: Please provide a clear question. Why do you want to redefine models, instead of simply creating them in their correct form? This question might seem pointless to you, but note that your use case seems rather rare. Also provide a [mcve]. The error you're getting cannot be reproduced with the example code given.

Comment: @SuperShoot, See if the edit helps.

Answer (score 2):

Originally, the error you say the PK reassignment is causing is:

```
InvalidRequestError: Instance <B_Table at 0x104aa1d68> cannot be refreshed - 
it's not persistent and does not contain a full primary key.
```

I don't get that running you MCVE, instead I get a pretty helpful warning first:

> SAWarning: Column 'B_Table.A_TableId' is marked as a member of the
>   primary key for table 'B_Table', but has no Python-side or server-side
>   default generator indicated, nor does it indicate 'autoincrement=True'
>   or 'nullable=True', and no explicit value is passed.  Primary key
>   columns typically may not store NULL.

And a very detailed exception message when the script fails:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Instance  has
>   a NULL identity key.  If this is an auto-generated value, check that
>   the database table allows generation of new primary key values, and
>   that the mapped Column object is configured to expect these generated
>   values.  Ensure also that this flush() is not occurring at an
>   inappropriate time, such as within a load() event.

So assuming that the example accurately describes your problem, the answer is straightforward. A primary key cannot be null.

`A_Table` inherits off `Base`:

```
class A_Table(Base):
    pass
```

`Base` gives `A_Table` an `autoincrement` PK through `declared_attr` `id()`:

```
@declared_attr
def id(cls):
    return Column(Integer, cls.seq, unique=True, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
```

Similarly, `B_Table` is defined off `Base` but the PK is overwritten in `possibleSolution()` such that it becomes a `ForeignKey` to `A_Table`:

```
PrimaryKeyConstraint(Column('A_TableId', Integer(), ForeignKey('A_Table.id'), table=<B_Table>, primary_key=True, nullable=False))
```

Then, we instantiate an instance of `A_Table` without any kwargs and immediately allocate the `id` attribute of instance `a` to field `A_TableId` when constructing `b`:

```
a = A_Table()
b = B_Table(A_TableId=a.id)
```

At this point we can stop and inspect the attribute values of each:

```
print(a.id, b.A_TableId)
# None None
```

`a.id` is `None` because it's an `autoincrement` which needs to be populated by the database, not the ORM. So SQLAlchemy doesn't know it's value until after the instance is flushed to the database.

So what happens if we include a `flush()` operation after adding instance `a` to the `session`:

```
a = A_Table()
session.add(a)
session.flush()
b = B_Table(A_TableId=a.id)
print(a.id, b.A_TableId)
# 1 1
```

So by issuing the `flush` first, we've got a value for `a.id`, meaning that we also have a value for b.A_TableId.

```
session.add(b)
session.commit()
# no error
```

Comment: This works for SQLite _only_. I replicated the error `InvalidRequestError: Instance <B_Table at 0x1073fe518> cannot be refreshed - it's not  persistent and does not contain a full primary key.
` when using a locally-hosted PostgreSQL database. When I _only_ change the engine connection string to an in-memory SQLite database, the error disappears. By the way, thank you for taking the time trying to solve this.